# Round only elements exceeding 1

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, rounding

I'm trying to run a simple custom function `test` that takes a vector `x` and rounds the contents if the entry is greater than 1, returning a new vector. For instance, for input `x <- c(.5, .2, 1.6, 7.9)` I would expect `test(x)` to output `[1] 0.5 0.2 2 8`.

However, my code either returns 1 entry or only alters 1 entry and leaves the rest of the output blank.

```
test <- function(x) {
  nr <- nrow(x)
  e <- numeric(nr)
  for (i in x) {
    if(i > 1) {
      e <- round(i, 1) 
    }
    else {
      e <- i 
    }
  }
  return(e)
}
```

How do I iterate through a predetermined list instead of a range of integers?

Comment: Is `x` a list, a data.frame or a vector? Is `e` a number or a vector or a list/data.frame? Is `i` a number or something else? What kind of thing do you want `test` to return.  It might help is you gave a toy example of what you would like `x` and `test(x)` to be if your function worked.

Comment: you are overwritting `e` to be a single value, use `e[i] <- round(x[i], 1)`

Comment: So for example:
    weight <- c(.5, .2, 1.6, 7.9)
    test(weight)
should return
[1] 0.5 0.2 2 8

nongkrong, that makes sense but its still pulling an error:
Warning messages:
1: In if (i > 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In e[i] <- i :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Answer (score 1):

Instead of performing a for loop with an embedded if statement, it would be more efficient (both in terms of runtime and amount of code written) to use `ifelse`. You would transform your entire function to a single line of code:

```
test <- function(x) ifelse(x > 1, round(x, 0), x)
```

Here it is in action:

```
x <- c(.5, .2, 1.6, 7.9)
test(x)
# [1] 0.5 0.2 2.0 8.0
```